# ng-grid sum of values in aggregate row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid with three columns (name, value, machine) that displays metrics (name, value) from three different computers (as indicated in machine column). Rather than displaying three lines for each metric, I have set `groups: ['name']` in the gridOptions; however, I cannot figure out how to make the aggregate row display the sum of the values. Is there a way to access the values of the rows in each group to calculate a sum?

This is what I want to see (7, 10, 4, 6 on the aggregate rows in the value column):

```
  NAME           VALUE     MACHINE
v metric1 (3)    7
  metric1        3         comp-a
  metric1        2         comp-b
  metric1        2         comp-c
> metric2 (3)    10
> metric3 (3)    4
v metric4 (3)    6
  metric4        5         comp-a
  metric4        0         comp-b
  metric5        1         comp-c
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe this depends heavily on the version of the grid you're using.  I found some solutions online to this same problem but the functions and internal data model of the grid have changed between the writings I found and the current version, I'll post my current solution below but you may have to dig through the grid code a bit to find the template in your version then just tweak/inspect from there.

Comment: I am using ng-grid version 2.0.5

Comment: Honestly just realized I'm not sure which one I'm on at this point, just have the timestamp to go off of... I'll post what I've done anyhow.

Comment: Did you manage to have the aggregation in their value columns like in the example above?  This is something I would like to achieve in a ng-grid in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and tried some proposed solutions I found but wasn't working with the version of the grid I have.  I searched the grid source and found the template that mine was using for aggregate rows and copied it then tweaked to include a call to a function on my method for parts of the display:

On my gridOptions I define the property shown below

```
aggregateTemplate: "<div ng-click=\"row.toggleExpand()\" ng-style=\"rowStyle(row)\" class=\"ngAggregate\">" +
    "    <span class=\"ngAggregateText\"><span class='ngAggregateTextLeading'>{{row.totalChildren()}} {{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}} {{entryMaybePlural(row)}}</span><span>Total Weight: {{aggFunc(row)}} lbs {{AggItemsLabel}}</span></span>" +
    "    <div class=\"{{row.aggClass()}}\"></div>" +
    "</div>" +
    ""
```

On the scope of the controller for the grid I have the functions

```
  $scope.aggFunc = function (row) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(row.children, function(cropEntry) {
      total+=cropEntry.entity.weight;
    });
    return total.toString();
  };
  $scope.entryMaybePlural = function (row) {
    if(row.children.length>1)
    {
      return "entries";
    }
    else
      return "entry";
  };
```

You'll see in both cases I pass the row in the template to the function in the controller scope, then I look at the property called children on the row (I just figured this out using the Chrome debugging tools when other attempts didn't work out).

PS my grid has this compilation comment in the top, though no version :|

```
/***********************************************
* ng-grid JavaScript Library
* Authors: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/README.md 
* License: MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
* Compiled At: 06/03/2013 21:19
***********************************************/
```